# Plots not showing with seaborn

Tags: matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I wanted to use seaborn but the mere lines

```
data = sns.load_dataset("iris")
# draw lineplot
sns.lineplot(x="sepal_length", y="sepal_width", data=data)
plt.show()
```

do not show anything.
I tried to use `plt.ion()`,

```
f = sns.lineplot(x="sepal_length", y="sepal_width", data=data)
f.figure
```

But these do not work either. I have nothing shown in the terminal.
I also tried `matplotlib.use('Agg')`.

I am currently on Ubuntu, using `matplotlib 3.5.2` and `seaborn 0.11.2` and I tried using python 3.10, `matplotlib 3.5.1` and `seaborn 0.11.1` and no combination works.
Does anyone have an idea of what could be the problem ?

Answer (score -1):

dont assign variable just type

sns.lineplot(x='sepal_length',y='sepal_width',data=data)
plt.show()[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x4CC.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).